# Solr: Is it possible to call the "concat" function in the source of the "copyField"？

Tags: java, solr, solrj

For example if I define the "copyField" below, the solr will throw this exception when startup：
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: copyField source :'concat('i1', id1)' is not a glob and doesn't match any explicit field or dynamicField.

```
<copyField source="concat('i1', id1)" dest="test" />
<copyField source="concat('i2', id2)" dest="test" />
```

But "concat('i1', id1)" can set to the "fl" of the query request without any errors.

Comment: you can try with Update request Preocessors from solr....https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_6/update-request-processors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can archive the same with the help of Update request Processors of Solr

You can use the `ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory` :

> Concatenates multiple values for fields matching the specified
> conditions using a configurable delimiter.

For Example :

1. Add a new updateRequestProcessorChain to solrconfig.xml:

> ```
> <updateRequestProcessorChain name="concatFields">
>   <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
>       <str name="source">field1</str> 
>       <str name="dest">field4</str> 
>     </processor> 
>   <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
>       <str name="fieldName">field4</str> 
>       <str name="delimiter">_</str> 
>     </processor>
>     <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" /> 
>     <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
> </updateRequestProcessorChain>
> ```

2. Add that chain to the appropriate update handler

> ```
> <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
>          <lst name="defaults">
>          <str name="stream.contentType">application/csv</str>
>          <str name="update.chain">concatFields</str>    </lst> </requestHandler>
> ```

More details on the Update processors are found on the link below.
[Update Request Processors](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_6/update-request-processors.html)

**Note** : Restart the Solr server and to index new documents.